# Basic angularJs directive on tomcat server

Tags: html, angularjs, tomcat

I am using Eclipse (dynamic web project), tomcat. Attached all the files and folder structure of the project is also attached.

I used http://localhost:8080/testing-AngularJS/ and http://localhost:8080/testing-AngularJS/Main.html

I am seeing blank page not the login page.

My Main file consist of login directive only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testAngular">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="appCode/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="appCntrl">
        <login-directive></login-directive>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js file has directive and config defined. Config file which routes to
login page.

```
var app = angular.module('testAngular', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/Login.html',
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'views/Login.html'
    });
}]);

app.controller('appCntrl', function ($scope, appService) {
    this.review = {};

    this.addReview = function (product) {

    };
});

app.directive('loginDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/appCode/views/Login.html'
        };
    }
);
```

Login.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Sign in</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>AFT ID</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="User ID" type="text" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="Password" type="password" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Login</a>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

WEB.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>testing-AngularJS</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Main.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

ERROR:
```

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (http://localhost:8080/testing-AngularJS/scripts/angular.min.js:87:78)
```

Comment: Have you checked your dev console in Chrome / Firefox for any javascript errors?

Comment: thank you for the reply, just checked it, shows as   Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/modulerr?p0=testAngular&p1=…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A427)

Comment: Switch out to the non-minified version of angular and run again.  Copy the whole error message to your question above.

Comment: i fixed the issue by injecting ngRoute to the module, but still it not loading..says resource not found. http://localhost:8080/views/Login.html

Comment: I can't tell where your actual templates are stored. If you watch your dev console network tab you can see where angular is trying to fetch your templates, and adjust the paths for templateUrl to use the right URL.

Comment: you are right, i resolved it now by changing the templateURl. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

```
 templateUrl:'views/Login.html'
```

instead of

```
 templateUrl:'/appCode/views/Login.html'
```

in your directive and

```
 templateUrl: 'views/Main.html',
```

in your routeProvider templateUrl

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the dependency on ngRoute in your module setup.  Try adding it in your `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('testAngular', ['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: i did that injection, as i said in earlier comment resource not found is the issue, i am assuming the path is wrong, templateUrl is the problem

Comment: You might need to add a `base href` tag to your document to get your templates loaded relative to your folder where your Main.html is.  Try adding to your `<head>` section, a `<base href="/testing-AngularJS/">` tag.  It should work without that, but it looks like your templates are trying to load from the parent folder for some reason.